# how to auto-run ntdpdate command?

Tags: centos, time-synchronization, ntpdate

I have a few dedicated servers and for some reason they are totally unable to mantain the time properly synchronized, every few days they start having differences of minutes in the clock. So I have to manually open Putty, connect, login, and run the `ntpdate -u 0.ar.pool.ntp.org` command on each of them.

Since there's no way I can do this every day because I'm quite busy, the question is **exactly how can I create some kind of cron that auto-runs this command every day on each server**. I have full root access to all servers, they have CentOs and DirectAdmin.
Thanks.-

Answer (score 16):

No need to use cron for this task. Much better to install and configure ntpd (special daemon  for *continuous* time sync).

1. `sudo yum install ntp`
2. `sudo chkconfig ntpd on`
3. `sudo nano  /etc/ntp.conf`
4. you are from Argentina, right? comment/remove all the default CentOS ntp servers, you can add your own [time-servers for Argentina](http://www.pool.ntp.org/zone/ar), for example

   ```
   server 0.ar.pool.ntp.org
   server 1.south-america.pool.ntp.org
   server 0.south-america.pool.ntp.org
   ```
5. After you are done with the configuration, just start the ntp service: `sudo service ntpd start`
6. To check if the NTP service is synchronizing:

   ```
   sudo ntpq -pn
   sudo tail -f /var/log/messages
   ```

Comment: In fact, ntp-date is just a stripped-down version of NTPD, used for one-shot sync.

Comment: Thanks, but on one of the servers this didn't work, this is the tail result:Apr  1 21:46:37 v ntpd[3761]: Listening on interface eth1, 10.0.0.5#123 Enabled
Apr  1 21:46:37 v ntpd[3761]: kernel time sync status 0040
Apr  1 21:46:37 v ntpd[3761]: getaddrinfo: "::1" invalid host address, ignored
Apr  1 21:46:37 v kernel: megasr[ahci]: unable to retreive proper sense data
Apr  1 21:47:56 v kernel: ip_conntrack: table full, dropping packet.
Apr  1 21:47:58 v kernel: megasr[ahci]: unable to retreive proper sense data
Apr  1 21:48:30 v last message repeated 105 times

Comment: @Andrew, is was the 1st of April, nevermind

Comment: The only caution I'd add is that I consider ntpd's access restriction behavior pretty obtuse.  http://support.ntp.org/bin/view/Support/AccessRestrictions#Section_6.5.1.2 has flow chart documentation for locking it down.  Nice if you have a firewall, a potential mandate if you don't.

Answer (score 7):

Instead of using `ntpdate` which resets time hardly at once, consider using NTP daemon (`ntp` packet). It slows down or fastens system clock to match NTP-server.